# Apache2 send all request to index.php with GET parameters

Tags: apache

I have got this code for apache. It sends all requests to index.php but I lost all GET parameters. How to rewrite it, so I don't lost the parameters.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /srv/http/framework
    ServerName framework.localhost
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond $1 !^(static)
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [PT]
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in /etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf I have changed

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(static)
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [PT]
```

for

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(static)
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: A little explanation why this worked over the previous one: *QSA* means query string append. The default discards existing query string at rewrite and replaces it with new ones, *QSA* enables to combine existing query strings. the opposite is *QSD* (query string discard) The *L* flag tells to stop further execution

Comment: but with that there is a problem if you import in your index some files like css or js all request will be redirect to same index.php